# How would you check the genuinity of an ASP.Net developer by asking him questions or specific

Tags: asp.net

How would you check the genuinity of an ASP.Net developer by asking him questions or specific

Comment: or specific what? Helps if you ask him questions in complete sentences :/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few topics off the top of my head I'd probably base interview questions on:

Ask them about page life cycle events- you'd expect them to be able talk about Page_load, Pre_Render etc and why they might use them.

Ask them about the sorts of ASP.NET projects they worked on- this will usually stop someone who hasn't really used ASP.NET.

Ask them what frameworks they've used or ones they've hated using (Microsoft UIP springs to mind). What their favourite features are.

Get them to talk about ViewState, if they know what this is then ask them about ControlState. Ask them to describe what has changed in the various versions of ASP.NET.

Also ask them what they think about ASP.NET MVC. If they haven't heard of this then they probably don't follow the recent developments in the technology.

Ask them if they have used the ASP.NET AJAX framework. Have they heard of JQuery?

Also ask them if they read any blogs- Scott Gu's is a favourite amongst ASP.NET devs.

Ask them how they'd go about architecting an ASP.NET app.

Ask them about SQL Server. Do they know that readers block writers (only really useful for high hit websites)?

Ask them about the Provider pattern and why it is useful in ASP.NET. Also stuff on Membership/Role APIs etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to give them a simple task of data access to a database, perhaps a postback form, and if you're feeling like you want to test them a little more, perhaps get them to implement a simple interface, or inherit from something you've created for the test to bring in further functionality that they must use.  That covers the basics I guess, but the basics are far wider than just the above.

You could be cruel and disable access to the internet, but I know that I forget syntax far more than I care to admit, and often google for syntax/functionality reminders, so that'd be up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Ask him to write a complete web page using nothing but code-behind (in C# or VB flavour).

Bonus points for adding postback ability too  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean [genuineness](http://dictionary.reference.com/dic?q=genuineness&search=search). Just ask him about Session and Dynamic Data ... Ask him how long it would take to produce one simple page with form and gridview from a database. If it takes more than 10 minutes or the guy starts to use the designer window he is not a professional in asp.net ... Sorry GUI lovers. If you do not understand the code and have to cheat from GUI to build something ... you are lost

Comment: some people can deliver faster in split view simply because of the GUI helpers - why would I want to remember the syntax of a gridview boundcolumn field?  I use resharper to assist with short cuts in code, is that cheating too?

Comment: Given that the officially-written, Microsoft-published books show the use of the GUI tools in developing, your opinion (for that is all that it is) in this particular area seems a touch fascistic...

Answer (score 0):

[This seems to have some very good interview style questions and answers](http://blogs.crsw.com/mark/articles/254.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should ask him with easy question. But this question show his idea(+ understanding of asp.net framework). Please don't ask him with very technical question. Because he will be textbox reader more than asp.net developer.

Comment: +1 to offset the downvote.  Your english isn't perfect, but your answer is valid -- I think the point you're trying to make is not to ask questions that are too specific, e.g. "what's the signature of the Cache.Add() method," but rather ask more general questions like "what are the pros and cons of ViewState".

Comment: Thanks. I mean something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of interview questions on the net, I just grabbed the ones I liked.

I like it when I am asked to code a simple app and email it in after the interview. Even something as simple as coding a page hit counter.

When employers are thorough with interviewing programmers, it makes me want the job more.